# Back Navigation using Xamarin Razor on WebViewClient

Tags: razor, xamarin, cross-platform, webviewclient

Please help me to find the way how to navigate back on webviewclient using back button on android.
I am using Xamarin hybrid app using Razor views,

I am using loadDataWithBaseURL method to find each method and move on that page, like following:

```
if (method == "SignIn")///sign-in.html
{
    var template = new SignIn();
    var page = template.GenerateString();
    webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", page, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
}
```

The above code I am using in ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, string Url)
the URL is passed as "hybrid:SignIn?"

Now back navigation is not working either on using OnBackPressed() method, or using OnKeyDown()

I also tried, WebBackForwardList, I can see in debug mode te current items in it , but no any url to go back on. 
The url is always "about:blank"

and page is showing blank on GoBack() method.

Comment: Did you find your solution ? I just want to know that it is possible to create entire app using Xamarin and Razor. Please provide any resources if you know. I am trying to create a gridview like Telerik RadGrid for Winforms but it is not available in Xamarin. Now I come to know about razor in Xamarin, so i think of giving it a try.